# Pandas dataframe keep rows with certain conditions met else keep whatever is available

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have the following dataframe called df1:

```
    name    shortname location   type
0   TexasA  TXA       Canada     Main
1   TexasA  TXA       US         Main
2   TexasA  TXA ZZ    US         Sub-par
3   TexasA  TXA ZZ 2  US         Sub-par2
4   Oregon  ORGN      US         Main
5   Ontario ONT2      Canada     Sub-par
...........
```

Then I have the following dataframe called df2:

```
    name    country
0   TexasA  US
1   Oregon  US
2   Ontario Canada
...........
```

I wish to merge the dataframes on the name and the final dataframe should be left with the following dataframe:

```
    name    shortname
0   TexasA  TXA
1   Oregon  ORGN
2   Ontario ONT2
...........
```

Right now when I do a merge with the following command,

```
finaldf = pd.merge(df2,df1,on=['name','shortname'],how='out')
```

, I am left with the following:

```
    name    shortname location   type
1   TexasA  TXA       US         Main
2   TexasA  TXA ZZ    US         Sub-par
3   TexasA  TXA ZZ 2  US         Sub-par2
4   Oregon  ORGN      US         Main
6   Ontario ONT2      Canada     Sub-par
```

I only want to keep the the ones with the type Main, and if it's not available, I want to keep whatever is available, the type could be sub-par but it could be something else, how do i get that done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you want to get the `shortname` for every row `df2` from `df1` for the same `name` and `contry`/`location` and `type` 'Main'. If there's no such entry in `df1` then the same for any other type. You can do this by making two merges and then fill the missing values in the first result by the corresponding values from the second result using [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df_main = df1[df1.type.eq('Main')].merge(df2, left_on=['name','location'], right_on=['name','country'], how='right')
df_sub = df1[df1.type.ne('Main')].merge(df2, left_on=['name','location'], right_on=['name','country'], how='right')
df_main.combine_first(df_sub).dropna()[['name', 'shortname']]
```

Result:

```
      name shortname
0   TexasA       TXA
1   Oregon      ORGN
2  Ontario      ONT2
```